# Qt SQLite no query or parameter count mismatch

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Juggling between receiving 2 different errors.

```
void summary::on_pushButton_saveSummary_clicked()   
{
    if(db.open())
    {
        query.exec("insert or replace into [PN:"+partNum+" CN:"+chargeNum+"](total, defects, rust) values(1, 2, 3)");
        if (!query.exec())
        {
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
        qDebug() << query.exec()<<endl;
        }
     }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << db.lastError();
    }
}
```

The above gives error: QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")

While:

```
void summary::on_pushButton_saveSummary_clicked()
{
    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "db open";
        int a = 3;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 3;

        query.prepare("insert into [PN:"+partNum+" CN:"+chargeNum+"](total, defects, rust) values(:total, :defects, :rust)");
        query.bindValue(":total", a);
        query.bindValue(":defects", b);
        query.bindValue(":rust", c);

        if (!query.exec())
        {
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
        qDebug() << query.exec()<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << db.lastError();
    }
}
```

Yields: QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")

The Constructor has:

```
db.setDatabaseName("/home/igraves/Databases/testdb");
db.open();
QString partNum = "134345";
QString chargeNum = "3452";
query.prepare("create table if not exists [PN:"+partNum+" CN:"+chargeNum+"](total int, defects int, rust int)");
query.exec();
```

The table is being create, I can see it. So I am guessing syntax? Although it is as the Qt wiki writes it...

Edit:
Adding some .h stuff

```
    QString partNum;
    QString chargeNum;
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    QSqlQuery query;
```

Answer: It was my QString variables being temporary, after the constructor was done, they went out of scope. Changed my .h

```
QString partNum = "124124";
QString chargeNum = "234234";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least the following errors:

- You do not set the database path.
- Do not open the database when creating the table.
- "134345" and "3452" are being assigned to temporary variables instead of class members

Considering the above, the following must be in the constructor:

```cpp
partNum = "134345";
chargeNum = "3452";
db.setDatabaseName("/path/of/database.db");
if(db.open())
    query.exec(QString("create table if not exists [PN:%1 CN:%2](total int, defects int, rust int)")
               .arg(partNum)
               .arg(chargeNum));
```

Comment: Apologies, those were in there, but I forgot to add them in the codeblock.